# Trackbar not sending TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING notification

Tags: winapi, trackbar

I have a programmatically created trackbar control (`TRACKBAR_CLASS`). I would like to be notified of scrolling changes using `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING`. However, I am currently not receiving that notification. I have monitored all the `WM_NOTIFY` messages sent by the control, and I have only seen the other two: `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` (-12) and `NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE` (-16).

The pertinent excerpts of the code (which I inherited) are these:

```cpp
// this code creates the window

HWND hwndControl = CreateWindowEx(
          0,
          TRACKBAR_CLASS,
          NULL,
          TBS_AUTOTICKS | TBS_TOP | TBS_HORZ | TBS_RIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height,
          parentWindow,
          dlgID,
          hInstance,        
          NULL);

//and the WM_NOTIFY routine:

bool HandleWMNotify(WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
   if (! controlIsMyTrackBar) return false; // abbreviated pseudocode

   switch(((LPNMHDR) lparam)->code)
   {
      case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
          break; //This case hits whenever the control draws itself.

      case NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE:
          break; //This case hits whenever I release the mouse on the control.
 
      case TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING:
          break; //This case never hits. :-(

      default:
          break; //This case never hits either (which is expected behavior).
   }
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-control-reference) for the Trackbar offers `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` as an option for monitoring trackbar changes. But weirdly, this [overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-controls) does not mention any of the `WM_NOTIFY` events in its **Trackbar Notification Messages** section.

I have found a number of other questions similar to this one, but the answers basically just point back to one of these two documentation pages that seem not exactly to be in agreement with each other.

If I have to, I will use `WM_HSCROLL`, but `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` would be preferable.

Comment: Did you try setting the `TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE` style?

Comment: At your suggestion I tried `TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE`, and now I get the `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` notification. But it is coming *before* instead of *after* the control changes value, which is the reverse of what I want. The docs seem to imply that you can get notified after. In any case there is no mention (that I found) of needing `TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE` to be set in order to get it.

Comment: I think you're reading more into the docs than is there. Look at what the return value is documented as meaning. How can that work if it comes afterwards?

Comment: @rpatters1 "*But it is coming before instead of after the control changes value*" - that is its [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/trackbar-control-styles): "*Trackbar should notify parent **before** repositioning the slider due to user action (enables snapping).*" I mean, it literally says TBS_NOTIFY**BEFORE**MOVE right in its name.

Comment: I know what TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE means. Sheesh. I'm talking about the TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING notification. It is very unclear in the docs that this notification requires  TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE. By that I mean, TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE is never mentioned by name, and to the contrary the doc implies you can use the notification instead of WM_H/VSCROLL (without qualification).

Comment: If Jonathan Potter wants to write up his original comment as answer, I'll check it.

Comment: The docs, in typical Microsoft fashion, do leave a lot to the imagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TRBN_THUMBPOSCHANGING` notification is sent before the thumb control moves; it seems intended to allow for snapping to custom positions, and presumably lets you block and/or modify the position the thumb moves to.

The documentation on this notification message is not especially clear, but the note about the return value does imply that it is sent **before** the control changes value:

> Return TRUE to prevent the thumb from moving to the specified position.

Obviously this would not make sense if it was sent after the control had already moved.

Another clue is in the name of the message; if you look at the listview control, for example, it has `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` and `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` notification messages. the "changing" message is sent before the change occurs, and the "changed" message is sent afterwards. Of course the trackbar seems to have no such "changed" message - that function being, presumably, filled by `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL`.

Once we know that the message is sent before the thumb moves, the name of the `TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE` style makes sense - and indeed, this style needs to be set in order to receive these notifications.

The line in the remarks section of the documentation is quite confusing:

> Send this notification to clients that do not listen for WM_HSCROLL or WM_VSCROLL messages

To me this reads as an internal comment that wasn't intended for public documentation.